# Error 'File doesn't exist' when running Django manage.py

Tags: django, error-handling

Whenever I run Django 'python manage.py runserver', makemigrations or migrate I get the following error :

```
(env) mark@mysite$ python manage.py runserver
File doesn't exist
File doesn't exist
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 12, 2020 - 16:03:37
Django version 3.0.3, using settings 'mysite.settings.dev'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

This is a very unhelpful error, are there any logs I can look in to find out which file is missing?

I have tried re-installing Django, and deleting and recreating the site migrations and database but the error persists.  The site otherwise runs fine so I have no clue as to what is going on.

Any suggestions in how I can fault find this would be really appreciated.  I am also using Wagtail but I don't think the error is related to that.

Comment: Are you in the directory where is manage.py file is located?

Comment: show us your path and the project architecture, please

Comment: It just appears as you are not on the directory where `manage.py` is located.

Comment: To be clear I have several other projects running fine.  I am in the directory where manage.py is located, and all the commands work perfectly.  My only issue is I am getting an error message. I updated the example to show the command working.

Comment: Have you recently started using 'python-dotenv'?  If so have you created a .env file?

Comment: Somehow the question is now screwed, because there is no error message. From what you describe in the first line, it could also be that you didn't write your app into settings.py INSTALLED_APPS? What happens if you try ```python manage.py makemigrations APPNAME```?

Comment: @maschu the error message appears twice in the question above.  If I run python **manage.py makemigrations APPNAME** the error also appeared. Inyoka is right, the message is from the dotenv package not having a configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message **'File doesn't exist'** is generated by the package **python-dotenv**.

Either create a file called **.env** in your site containing any environmental variables you do not want stored in your GitHub commits.  (Also ensure this file is listed in your **.gitignore** file. 
You can do this by running the following command in the directory containing the gitignore file ...

```
echo '.env >> .gitignore
```

Alternatively if you are not using it, uninstall python-dotenv ..

```
pip uninstall python-dotenv
```

... and make sure it is not listed in **requirements.txt** so it doesn't get reinstalled.

Comment: Great, thank you. I had a plan to use dotenv and didn't get around to configuring it.  If the error had a little more information I probably could have figured it out myself.